# I can not have two datasources configured JPA Spring XML WildFly

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, wildfly

Spring config in xml

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="datas1" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    jndi-name="java:/jndi1" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="datas2" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    jndi-name="java:/jndi2" />

<bean id="EntityM"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datas1" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="package.persistence.entity" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="EntityM" />
</bean>
```

The Excpetion is:

Context initialization failed: `org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'springSessionJdbcOperations' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/session/jdbc/config/annotation/web/http/JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'springSessionJdbcOperations' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: datas1,datas2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: datas1,jndi2.`

I can not have two datasources configured, The first datasource is to the entityManagar and second datasource is to call stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JdbcSessionConfiguration expects a bean of type 'DataSource' with name 'dataSource'. 
If this cannot be found, spring tries to use a bean of type 'DataSource', ignoring the name. Because there are two beans of this type, the exception is thrown.

**Solution :**
Rename the DataSource bean, that you want to use with the EntityManager from
'datas1' to 'dataSource'.

Spring should than be able to create JdbcSessionConfiguration and you can use the 'datas2' for whatever you need.